# NetSuite: SuiteScript to Set out-of-stock behavior

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to deploy a SuiteScript to automatically set the Out-of-stock behavior based on the quantity available

The logic goes something like this

**If (quantityAvailable = 0) => Set outofstockbehavior to "Disallow back orders but display out-of-stock message"**

else => Set outofstockbehavior to "Allow back orders with no out-of-stock message"

**For the sake of testing, I'm limiting it to one item bearing the ID 10336**

Following is the JS script

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

/* Disallow back orders but display out-of-stock message: DISABLE
Allow back orders but display out-of-stock message: ENABLE
Remove item when out-of-stock: REMOVE
Allow back orders with no out-of-stock message: ENABLEMSG
*/


define(['N/record', 'N/search'], function(record, search) {
    function execute(context) {
        // Load the item record
        var itemRecord = record.load({
            type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            id: 10336,
            isDynamic: false,
        });

        // Get the out-of-stock behavior
        var outOfStockBehavior = itemRecord.getValue({
            fieldId: 'outofstockbehavior'
        });

        var quantityAvailable = itemRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'quantityavailable'
                });

        // Set the out-of-stock behavior based on the quantity available
            if (quantityAvailable > 0) {
                itemRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'outofstockbehavior',
                    value: record.FieldValue.ENABLE
                });
            } else {
                itemRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'outofstockbehavior',
                    value: record.FieldValue.DISABLE
                });
            }

            // Save the item record
            itemRecord.save();



        // Log the out-of-stock behavior
        log.debug({
            title: 'Item Out-of-Stock Behavior',
            details: 'Item ID: 10336, Out-of-Stock Behavior: ' + outOfStockBehavior
        });
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

And I'm getting the following error in Debugger:

[JS_EXCEPTION org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "DISABLE" from undefined (3152023 update item-specific-oosb.js$1364604$debugger.user#39)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJ9H.png)

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`FieldValue` isn't a defined property on the record object. You should simply reference the ID of the select option and if you wanted to be nice to yourself, make an Enum.

```
// declare this at the top of your file within the define block
var Behavior = {
  ENABLED: 1, // or whatever the internal ID is 
  DISABLED: 2, // or whatever the internal ID is
};

// ... script logic

itemRecord.setValue({
  fieldId: 'outofstockbehavior',
  value: Behavior.ENABLED,
});

// ... the rest of your script
```